# Delete query not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using linq to delete data from database. I googled, and made query. I am using following query.

When i put debugger over this, its not showing any error. Its going fine. But when I check my database , record does not gets delete.

At the same time doing operation for insert:

```
 splitTradeDataContext db = new splitTradeDataContext();
                    tradeFile tlbTradeFile = new tradeFile();

 tlbTradeFile.TradeNo = TradeNo + "_A";
               tlbTradeFile.Status = Status;
               tlbTradeFile.Scrip_Code = Scrip_Code;
               tlbTradeFile.Inst_Type = Inst_Type;
               tlbTradeFile.Expirydate = Expirydate;
               tlbTradeFile.Strike_price = Strike_price;
               tlbTradeFile.Option_type = Option_type;
               tlbTradeFile.Sec_Name = Sec_Name;
               tlbTradeFile.BookType = BookType;
               tlbTradeFile.BookTypeName = BookTypeName;
               tlbTradeFile.TerminalId = TerminalId;
               tlbTradeFile.Branch_Id = Branch_Id;
               tlbTradeFile.Buy_Sell = Buy_Sell;
               tlbTradeFile.Trade_Qty = Trade_Qty;
               tlbTradeFile.Market_Rate = Market_Rate;
               tlbTradeFile.Pro_cli = Pro_cli;
               tlbTradeFile.Party_Code = Party_Code + "_A";
               tlbTradeFile.ParticipantCode = ParticipantCode;
               tlbTradeFile.O_C_Flag = O_C_Flag;
               tlbTradeFile.Sauda_Date = Sauda_Date;
               tlbTradeFile.TradeModified = TradeModified;
               tlbTradeFile.OrderNo = OrderNo;
               tlbTradeFile.Opp_Broker_Id = Opp_Broker_Id;
               tlbTradeFile.OrderTime = OrderTime;
               tlbTradeFile.UnknowkNum = UnknowkNum;

 var remove = from aremove in db.tradeFiles
              where aremove.ID==int.Parse(gvTradeFile.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
              select aremove;
 if(remove!=null)
    db.tradeFiles.DeleteAllOnSubmit(remove);
```

What can be problem? Am I using wrong query? Or any thing still remained from me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `SubmitChanges` anywhere in your code you need to do:

```
db.SubmitChanges(); //if its LINQ to SQL
```

Comment: db.SubmitChanges() function is there. not finding db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @freelancer, you are probably using LINQ to SQL, you should call `db.SubmitChanges` that should do the job

Comment: fine. thank you. I was new with linq. It seems to be basic thing

Comment: @freelancer, this more about [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) than [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: I am inserting the data into database at the same time below this code.(above b.SubmitChanges();) its also not working

Comment: @freelancer, what is the error/exception you are getting, you may post a new question about it

Comment: @freelancer, You are not inserting the object in the dbContext, search  for`db.YourTable.Add(newobject)` and then call `db.SubmitChanges`

Comment: I used db.tradeFiles.InsertOnSubmit(tlbTradeFile); and it worked. db.YourTable.Add(newobject) showing me results for Linq to Dataset